# Can't use Partition by and select * in the same query

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I have the following error to the code below: "*FROM keyword not found where expected*"

```
SELECT *, MAX(Salary)
OVER (PARTITION BY ID_DEPT ORDER BY Salary DESC ) R
FROM SG_EMPLOYEES;
```

but when I change the asterisk with the names of each column everything works fine. So I just want to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: Not an answer, but the presence of the ORDER BY doesn't make much sense in this context.

Comment: Try `SG_EMPLOYEES.*` instead of just `*`

Comment: Yes. Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `*` in Oracle, it must be qualified if any other expressions are being selected.  So:

```
SELECT e.*,
       MAX(e.Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID_DEPT ORDER BY e.Salary DESC) as R
FROM SG_EMPLOYEES e;
```

Note that I'm a big fan of qualifying all column names.

Your query actually seems very strange.  You don't need the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT e.*,
       MAX(e.Salary) OVER (PARTITION BY e.ID_DEPT) as R
FROM SG_EMPLOYEES e;
```

Your version is taking the cumulative maximum and then ordering the salaries from the highest to the lowest -- so the cumulative is the same as the overall max.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that aliases for analytical functions are considered when invoke select asterisk so that result in an error.